# Adding Data grid view as a child node in a Tree View

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

Basically, I'm working on a winforms application. Now I'm stuck in a problem in which I want a tree grid view that displays nodes in `DataGridView`. I already used customized `DataGridView` that that displays child nodes. But what I want is to add another `DataGridView` in a child node. Meaning, when a user expands a node, a data grid view displays as a child node. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following code project article in which a Dropdown box is added as a treenode item. The article extends the TreeNode and adds a ComboxBox. It should be fairly simple to extend to a DataGridView

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14544/A-TreeView-Control-with-ComboBox-Dropdown-Nodes